# tkinter 'invaild command error' - how to change text box or label's setting with a method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

class Win:
    def __init__(self):
        root=Tk()
        root.title("Counter")
        root.geometry("600x600")
        root.configure(background = "green")
        self.widget = App(root)

        self.widget.creat_widgets()
        root.mainloop()
        self.widget.test_change()

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)

    def creat_widgets(self):
        self.text = Text(self, bg = 'grey', width=9, height=6)
        self.text.pack()

    def test_change(self):
        self.text['bg'] = 'black'

Win()
```

I wanted to change text box's background color to black from grey.
But instead I got this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
    Win()
  File "test.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.widget.test_change()
  File "test.py", line 25, in test_change
    self.text['bg'] = 'black'
  File
"C:\Users\HB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
line 1337, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
File
"C:\Users\HB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
line 1330, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File
"C:\Users\HB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",     line 1321, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".1652028503152.1652028502536"
```

I've learned this has sth to do with `mainloop()` but I still have no idea how to properly change `self.text`'s setting with method. Changing mainloop's position is out of question since I want to use this code for card game gui where the color change needs to happen every sequence (or round) in accordance with player interaction. Changing `mainloop`'s position might work but every change would happen instantly.

Is there anyway I can change widget setting with method?

Comment: Code appearing after `mainloop` won't execute until after the window is closed (and this may cause errors, for example if you try to configure a widget that no longer exists because the user Xed out of the window where it lived). Code appearing before `mainloop` will execute before the window opens. If you want code to execute while the window is open, you need to use `root.after` or [event binding](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).

Comment: What event should change the widget's color? `tlinter` is event-driven although you can arrange for things to happen after a certain amount of time using the universal widget [`after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method.